# TCP Server closes connection after first message

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, using, tcpserver

i have the following code executed by a listening Thread. What it does: Reading the first Message as the total message length then assemble all packets to a big data array. (Im sending images) It all works as intended. 

But after the first image is recieved and the function is done. ("ImageLengthResetted" gets printed) It closes the connection. 
 I think this is due the fact i am running out of the scope from:

```
using(connectedTcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient())
```

and thats what kills the connection. How can i keep this connection open?
Adding another

```
while(true)
```

after i've been connected wont do the trick. As well as executing the while loop completle after the using statments.

```
private void ListenForIncommingRequests()
{
    try
    {
        // Create listener on localhost port 8052.  
        localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(IPadrr);
        Debug.Log(localAddr);
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
        Debug.Log("Before Init tcplistern");
        tcpListener.Start();
        Debug.Log("Server is listening");
        Byte[] dataRecieved = new Byte[SEND_RECIEVE_COUNT];
        while (true)
        {
            using (connectedTcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient())
            {
                Debug.Log("Accepted TCP Client");
                // Get a stream object for reading                  
                using (NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream())
                {
                    int length;
                    Debug.Log("Accepted Stream");
                    // Read incomming stream into byte arrary.                      
                    while ((length = stream.Read(dataRecieved, 0, dataRecieved.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("receiving Loop lengt: " + length);
                        counterReceived++;
                        //Get Message length with first message
                        if (messageLength == 0)
                        {
                            messageLength = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(dataRecieved, 0);
                            data = new byte[messageLength];
                            messageJunks = messageLength / SEND_RECIEVE_COUNT;
                            restMessage = messageLength % SEND_RECIEVE_COUNT;
                            junkCounter = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (junkCounter < messageJunks)
                            {
                                Array.Copy(dataRecieved, 0, data, junkCounter * SEND_RECIEVE_COUNT, SEND_RECIEVE_COUNT);
                                junkCounter++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Array.Copy(dataRecieved, 0, data, junkCounter * SEND_RECIEVE_COUNT, restMessage);
                                //Whole Message recieved, reset Message length
                                messageLength = 0;
                                readyToDisplay = true;
                                Debug.Log("ImageLengthResetteed");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception socketException)
    {
        Debug.Log("SocketException " + socketException.ToString());
    }
}
```

Client Side opens send Thread with following function where socketConnection gets globally initialized on the receiving thread of the client:

```
private void sendData(byte[] data)
{
    try
    {
        //socketConnection = new TcpClient(IPadrr, port);
        using (NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream())
        {
            //Prepare the Length Array and send first
            byte[] dataLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length);
            int packagesSend = 0;
            int numberPackages = data.Length / SEND_RECIEVE_COUNT;
            if (stream.CanWrite)
            {
                for (counter = 0; counter <= data.Length; counter += SEND_RECIEVE_COUNT)
                {
                    if (counter == 0)
                    {
                        stream.Write(dataLength, 0, dataLength.Length);
                    }

                    if (packagesSend < numberPackages)
                    {
                        stream.Write(data, counter, SEND_RECIEVE_COUNT);
                        Thread.Sleep(20);
                        packagesSend++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stream.Write(data, counter, data.Length % SEND_RECIEVE_COUNT);
                        Debug.Log("FINDISCHD");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        print(err.ToString());
    }
}
```

Im glad for any help!

Comment: What does your client side code look like?

Comment: added the client code. But isnt it a server issue. The socket exception says remotehost closed the connection.

Comment: Remotehost is just the client that's not you local. So if the server code is throwing it the remotehost is the client and vice versa

Comment: You issue is with the While loop testing for the end of a stream.  A reading TCP stream is different from a file stream.  A filestream when you get to the end of the file you read a null and then stop reading and close the file.  With TCP you are at the end of the file to start even before you get any data.  Testing for zero will occur and then you are exiting the while loop and closing the connection.

Comment: Can you clean up your code a little and remove unnecessary parts? It is really difficult trying to understand what's going on like this

Comment: ah okay, got confused by the word "host". So i probably run out of the using(Networkstream) scope after sending and then the connection gets closed?

Comment: I believe I found the problem. It's on the client. You globally initialise `socketConnection` but then dispose of the Stream after the `using(NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream()`

Comment: so, globally init the stream as well to keep it open?

Comment: @jdweng but the connection isnt established in the while loop where im testing the length

Comment: I would init the TcpClient every time you need to call the web service. Except in cases where you know you're going to call the web service multiple times in a row

Comment: Thank you @MindSwipe i solved it! Init the stream globally does the trick

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was on the Client Side. I initialized the

```
NetworkStream stream;
```

now globally in the same function the    `socketConnection` gets init.